# sort Python dictionary with two keys

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary of this form:

text.items()[: 2]

```
[(('id','id1'), text', ('id','id1'), 'text', ('id','id1'), 'text')]
```

and i would like to sort it by id1. Any help?

Comment: `text.items()[:, 2]` I am sure whether that's a valid Python syntax-- A. B. Will you please elaborate?

Comment: That's not a dictionary.  It's a list with a tuple that has some tuples and items in it.

Comment: @iCodez Exactly! Also, the code highlighted earlier by me-- that's not a valid syntax, right?

Comment: @AkshatTripathi - Nope.  Python only uses colons it its slice notation.  Maybe he meant `text.items()[::2]`?

Comment: @iCodez unless for some strange reason it was a `numpy.array` in which case it'd be slice notation for the 3rd column... but, I guess that's unlikely, and we don't really know what it is from the code anyway...

Comment: I made a typo when writing the [:,2] but this is really a python dictionary. Could you please vote up to zero at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python dictionary is unordered and therefore can't be sorted. However as you seem to understand, it is possible to sort the value returned from its`items()`or`iteritems()`methods. If the keys of the dictionary were tuples as shown in your example, and you wanted to sort on the second value in each one of them,  here's an efficient way to do it:

```
text = {('idA','id2'): 'text',
        ('idB','id1'): 'text',
        ('idC','id3'): 'text',}

print sorted(text.iteritems(), key=lambda item: item[0][1])
```

Output:

```
[(('idB', 'id1'), 'text'), (('idA', 'id2'), 'text'), (('idC', 'id3'), 'text')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dictionary.items returns:

```
items = [(('id','id1'), 'text'), (('id','id1'), 'text'), (('id','id1'), 'text')]
```

you can sort by the first element of the the tuple by doing:

```
items.sort(key=lambda item: item[0][0])
```